# MailApp.sendEmail all messages blocked

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-api, google-workspace

Recently I have decided to upgrade to a GSuite account from the basic free gmail account. I have a collection of Google AppsScripts that manage a collection of forms/spreadsheets and send out notifications on changes. 
All scripts were copied into the new GSuite account and all seem to run well. All APIs used (spreadsheet, calendar, drive, forms work with the except of the script.send_mail which refuses to send any emails to external email addresses. If I set it to send emails to myself, it works fine, but to any external email and the message gets blocked with this message

```
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; Message rejected.  See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more information.
Last-Attempt-Date: Mon, 30 Sep 2019 14:02:02 -0700 (PDT)
```

I have created a very simple script to test it and it still fails. Code attached:

```js
function testSendMsg(){
  var subject = "Test Message";
  var message = " Testing 1 2 3..";
  var emailAddr = "emailaddressX@gmail.com";  // put correct email address here

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddr,subject,message);
}
```

Sending this email using the browser mail app works fine, only the script based email sends fail. Any help or pointers on this is appreciated.

Google Cloud Support was not able to find any solutions to this!

Comment: Can you try using GmailApp instead? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app.html

Comment: The problem with GmailApp is that it requires that you take your apps through a verification process. I have many apps which I use myself and not distributed to others. So the verification process would be too heavy to validate every single up if I go down that path.

Comment: I just tested GmailApp  and it actually works! but the MailApp.sendEmail does not. Very strange!

Comment: Was the test function run in a project you already had before upgrading to a GSuite account? If that's the case, try running it in a newly created project. Your issue might actually be due to an authentication problem (MailApp doesn't support aliases, so this might be the reason it works with GmailApp but not with MailApp).

Comment: No. I created a new project on the GSuite account which just contained the code you see above. Tested it with the MailApp.sendEmail and saw it fail. Then I tested it with the GmailApp and saw that it succeeded. So not sure why the MailApp.sendEmail function does not work on my GSuite account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MailApp.sendEmail method doesn't get through to accounts with URL in the body - Message Blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62156903/mailapp-sendemail-method-doesnt-get-through-to-accounts-with-url-in-the-body) Tl;Dr: There is an ongoing issue.

Answer (score 0):

After a week of frustration trying to figure out why this was not working, it just started working today with no changes. I suspect a new GSuite account is blocked from using this API at the beginning for some reason that I can not imagine and then released eventually after probation period is over.

Comment: After trying a few more times, the email blocking is back. So the issue is still present unfortunately.