# Problem in sending email by Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have been sending Email by Google Apps Script successfully for sometimes. However, when I open a new Google Workspace account and use the same code to send the same things to the same receiver, the new account does not work. I get a message of "Message blocked" from mailer-daemon@googlemail.com. It does not show any error description. When I send this message again in Gmail, the message can successfully reach the receiver. Any idea?
Things are perfectly fine in my old Google accounts but not OK in any Google accounts I tried this month.

```js
function myFunction() {
  MailApp.sendEmail("xxx@gmail.com","From yyy","Hello!");  
}
```

Comment: Use `GmailApp` instead of `MailApp`

Comment: For me this error is not happening? Where are you getting the error? In Apps Script itself? Or in the GMail with the UI? Have you tried to  follow @Rubén advice?

Comment: I have several accounts and the same code work for all my old account. But as I open a new account (even paid one), the mail cannot be sent. It seems that the code works but the mail is blocked by Google. I received a email from Mail Delivery Subsystem like this:Message rejected. See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR:

Gmail thinks you are a spammer. Changing `MailApp` for `GmailApp` should work. In your case:

```js
GmailApp.sendEmail("xxx@gmail.com","From yyy","Hello!");
```

### Full answer:

The reason this is happening is because Gmail is flagging your email as a possible spam. This is likely because it is a new account, the contents of the message and configuration (like sending only plain text, no `replyTo` or `noReply` configuration, etc.). The Google algorithm is probably quite complex and there is no clear way of testing it. [Here is an article talking about how to prevent being blocked](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en).

Other people that had this problem seem to have success using `GmailApp` instead of `MailApp` ([Stack Overflow question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175526/mailapp-sendemail-all-messages-blocked), [Stack OVerflow question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62156903/mailapp-sendemail-method-doesnt-get-through-to-accounts-with-url-in-the-body)). The reason is probably how the services internally work.