# Blocked emails with Google Apps Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I have a script that sends out emails just fine with our gmail account but when I try to run it with our Google Workspace account, the emails get blocked.  I've checked with the support at Google and they tell me our DKIM and SPF are setup correctly.  Any idea why the emails are getting blocked?  The same code should work in both a regular gmail account and a Workspace account, Right?

Comment: From what little I know about the Workspace Accounts they're supposed to have more security so perhaps there is an admin setting that prevent uses from sending emails to users outside of their domain.

Comment: Please have it checked with your workspace admin. [Reference](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2640542?hl=en#zippy=%2Cinitial-step-go-to-gmail-compliance-settings-in-the-admin-console%2Cstep-add-addresses-or-domains-that-you-want-to-allow)

Comment: I can send individual emails with no problem.  It is when I send them with my script that they get blocked although the same script works fine in a normal gmail account.

Comment: You mean you can send an email using your workspace account in mail.google.com but when you use the script to send an email to the same email address it is blocked?

Comment: Right, and I can forward the blocked emails to the customers one at a time.

Comment: Can you check if this will fix your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65595058/14606046